# No taskbar on startup if external monitor connected, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

With an external HDMI monitor connected, power on laptop (or restart Ubuntu), Ubuntu boots up, login, and no taskbar is displayed. How do you fix this? Running Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS on a laptop.  Tried the above sequence with 2 monitors. Same issue.

Start Ubuntu with no external monitor and it's good. The taskbar is there on the laptop screen.

Current workaround is: unplug external monitor, start Ubuntu, login, connect external monitor.

Comment: The launcher, by default, is on the primary monitor. You can change the settings.

Comment: Fixed in Ubuntu 22.04. Still an issue in 20.04 in mid Dec 22.

Comment: Issue is back again. Only occurs if a Bluetooth speaker is connected. Daily logins over month shows it's a clear pattern. With external monitor connected by HDMI: bluetooth speaker connected, Ubuntu user login, and no taskbar is displayed; vs Bluetooth speaker not connected, user login and taskbar is displayed. So the new workaround is start Ubuntu, turn off Bluetooth speaker, user login.